# Django intermediate table with a many-to-many field instead foreign key?

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-database, django-intermediate-table

I have 2 models in my application:

- User
- Tower

My goal is to associate many towers to a user using an intermediate table because I need to add a period of time.

So I have something like this in my models:

```py
class Tower(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField('Tower', through='Dates')

class Dates(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tower = models.ForeignKey('Tower', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    begin_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

But my goal was to have the field tower in class Dates to a many-to-many like this:

```py
tower = models.ManyToManyField('Tower', blank=True)
```

So that i can associate many towers to a user in a certain period. But unfortunately django says that i need to use forgeignkey to Tower and User classes.

Have any solution for this? To apply directly the many-to-many field in the intermediate table? Or I must create a new class, sort of a GroupTower, that have a many-to-many field to the Tower class? Something like this:

```py
class Tower(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class GroupTower(models.Model):
    tower = models.ManyToManyField('Tower', blank=True)

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField('Tower', through='Dates')

class Dates(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tower = models.ForeignKey('GroupTower', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    begin_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is so many ways that you can design the database.

An example:

```
class Tower(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField('UserTower')

class UserTower(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tower = models.ManyToManyField('Tower')
    begin_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

In this design you can add many `UserTower` instances to a user and each `UserTower` instance can have many towers.

Now if you query the members for a user:

```
User.objects.get(pk=1).members.all()
```

You will have members grouped by periods of time if you saved them this way but it requires you to write some codes to avoid duplicates for `begin_date`, `begin_date` and `user`.

And now if you need towers:

```
user_members = User.objects.get(pk=1).members.all().values_list('tower', flat=True)
towers = Tower.objects.filter(pk__in=user_members).distinct()
```

This design is okay only if you really don't want duplicates with same `begin_date` and `begin_date` which i can't find a reason for.

You can still have all the features if you add multiple instances with same `begin_date`, `begin_date` and `user` but different `tower`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was expecting. Thank you so much for your help.